# How to make IE fireevent on Client Side Image Map

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary, events, internet-explorer

I need to simulate a mouse click using IE on a client side image map. Which object should invoke the `fireEvent()`? It cannot be simply the `<area>` object since it could be referenced by 2 different `<img>`s. It cannot be the `<img>` since we need a way to tell which part of the img is clicked which is defined in the `<area>`  tag?

I've done some test with real mouse click on an client side image map. The event object generated from my click indicates (by the `event.srcElement` property) the event is generated from `<area>` tag. But when I tried to programmatically call the `<area>`'s `fireEvent()`, nothing happened!

Comment: Which event do you want to fire? Invoking `click()` on the `area` element works fine in IE - it doesn't in FF, though...

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
<img name="Area" src="Area.jpg" width="240" height="160" border="0" id="Area" usemap="#m_Area" alt="" /><map name="m_Area" id="m_Area">
<area shape="rect" id="A" coords="126,0,240,160" href="javascript:;" onclick="alert('a')" alt="" />
<area shape="rect" id="B" coords="0,0,126,160" href="javascript:;" onclick="alert('b')" alt="" />
</map>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('A').onclick()">Test</a>
```